# What is the difference between these two accuracy metrics?

Tags: tensorflow

To calculate the accuracy for a MNIST learning task I normally use this formulation *(gray line in image below)*:

```
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(self.target_placeholder, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.to_float(correct_pred))
```

Today, I did see that there is a tensorflow metric for this *(orange line in image below)*:

```
_, self.accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(tf.argmax(self.target_placeholder, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
```

But the resulting accuracy is consistently very different:

[image: accuracy]

With the tensorflow metric the accuracy is smoother and much worse.

**Why is this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your plot I understand that you compared both of those options during training.

The first option computes accuracy on the current input batch only. This explains why the plot is somewhat noisy, especially if the batch size is small. On the plus side, it will always be "up to date" since the resulting accuracy value at each step is 100% based on the current state of the model.

The second option actually computes a running average. It (along with other options in the `tf.metrics` module) is intended to compute overall accuracy for a stream of data, i.e. a dataset that doesn't fit into a single batch. As such, it is mostly used for evaluation purposes where you want to check the accuracy of an already-trained model on a held-out set of data. In your case of using it during training, the fact that it computes a running average explains the smoothness as well as the fact that the curve is "worse": The average will always include values from the very beginning of training where accuracy is obviously very low.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was not clear to me from the documentation that a moving average is computed with this metric.